# Need to implement array in xslt

Tags: xslt

I want to implement array like structure.The prototype of my need is

```
<xsl:variable name="alphabets">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</xsl:variable>
```

When i give input as 4, i should get 'd'. 
How to implement this..please help me..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:variable name="alphabets" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
    <xsl:param name="vAlphIndex" select="4"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($alphabets, $vAlphIndex, 1)"/>
    </xsl:template>        
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result will be:

```
d
```

Answer (score 2):

XSLT 2.0 supports sequences, which allow you to do

```
<xsl:variable name="alphabet" select="'a', 'b', 'c', ...."/>
<xsl:value-of select="$alphabet[4]"/>
```

In XSLT 1.0, for an "array of characters" as in your example, use a string. For more complex structures, use an XML element with child elements.